# Can I install rancher-agent on an existing server without breaking anything?

Tags: rancher

We have an existing server that's running a bunch of websites (nginx/haproxy/mysql).

We've created Docker containers for each website. We'd like to use Rancher to manage everything. (I've used Rancher on other projects and really like it, but I've always set up my Rancher cluster (?) from scratch.)

I've set up a Rancher host on another machine.

My question is, can I now install Rancher agent on our existing production server without breaking anything? Then spin up the containers, then shut down nginx?

tldr; installing Rancher agent on a server won't nuke anything that's already there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing the agent will not do anything to containers that are already running on the host.  They will be read and shown as "stand-alone containers" in the Rancher UI.

It will start up various rancher system containers, but those shouldn't break anything.

Comment: What about things that _aren't_ containers? Like nginx, mysql and other bits and pieces (half I don't know about) on the server?

Comment: The agent only manages containers. Whatever else is running on the host stays doing what it's doing.  Obviously if nginx is using port 80 you will not be able to create containers that publish port 80 on that host.